# Empty address in Struct

Tags: solidity, addresses, remix, struct

Why does `getProduct(..)` always return an empty address 0x00 on browser-solidity?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract Products {
    struct Product {
        bytes32 name;
        uint votes;
        address company;
    }

    mapping (uint => Product) products;
    mapping (address => uint) companyProductsCounter;
    uint private counter;

    function Products () {
        counter = 0;
    }

    function registerProduct( bytes32 productName) {
        products[counter++] = Product({name: productName, votes: 0, company: msg.sender});
    }

    function getProduct(uint code) constant returns (bytes32 name, uint votes, address company) {
        products[code].name;
        products[code].votes;
        products[code].company;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the `getProduct` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it because the return parameters of `getProduct(unit)` are left unset?

Try:

```
function getProduct(uint code) constant returns (bytes32 name, uint votes, address company) {
    name=products[code].name;
    votes=products[code].votes;
    company=products[code].company;
}
```